# Срок Тестирования приложения IOS

Tags: ios, swift

Доброго времени суток.

Разрабатываю мобильное приложение. ЯП swift

Приложение работает нормально без ошибок.
Тестирую на реальном устройстве, но без подписки AppleDeveloper.

Вопрос в том что приложение установленное на телефоне перестает работать примерно через пару дней.Просто не открывается и все.После сборки той же версии приложения, без каких то изменений,заливки её в телефон все снова работает.... пару дней.

Это специально сделано Apple? У всех разработчиков так?

Тогда возникает дополнительный вопрос:
Например я написал приложение только для себя.
Образно REST клиент,для своей службы управления умным домом) 
Собственно не нужно его выкладывать его в appstore,я хочу установить только на свой телефон и телефон жены.

Как это верно реализуется? поделитесь опытом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответы:

1. Да, срок ограничен подпиской приложения. Затем нужно снова переподписаться.
2. Нужно приобрести аккаунт разработчика, по другому никак. При этом не обязательно выкладывать в магазин.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Предполагал это. Подписку буду брать точно.